# Handwriting recognition in android studio

Tags: android, ocr

I need to recognize some text written on a postit. The text has no meaning, it is a succession of letters written in block capitals.
I inquired and discovered that it is a problem of localization of handwriting and then of recognition of the handwriting. There is google OCR, but those models only recognize English language phrases.

I leave you an example image:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIdk0.jpg)

I would like that, for each postit, the text is recognized, so for the first postit: "769213" for the second "ALHSFP"

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud Vision API is able to detect more than just "English language phrases". Try Google Translate; it can translate directly from camera input; Lens might also use the same. You could as well use [TensorFlow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite) on Android. [Keras](https://keras.io) is required for training models (won't run on Android).

For example:

- https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/handwriting
- https://towardsdatascience.com/build-a-handwritten-text-recognition-system-using-tensorflow-2326a3487cd5
- https://keras.io/examples/vision/handwriting_recognition/

---

The mere difference is, that the one requires a network connection, while the other doesn't.

Comment: I thank you for the answer.
My mistake was not to specify that I need it to work offline. I think I will try to use keras. After the training will be necessary to convert it to tflite and should it work on android without doing any preprocessing of the image?

Comment: As stated, you can only run TF Lite on Android; but there's a converter: https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert

Comment: Perfect, thank you.
So, in conclusion, if I have not misunderstood I must:
- Train the model with keras
- Convert it to tflite with the converter
- Import it on android
- Invoke the interpreter and use the run() method
Right?